# Pandas: Finding the mean of n rows, with variable n

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, moving-average

I have two dataframes, call them A and B. A has columns of elementID, startDate, endDate, while B has columns elementID, date, dataValue. I would like to add an "average" column to A. For any particular row in A, we should have `row.average = B[(B.elementID==row.elementID) & (row.startDate <= B.date) & (row.endDate >= B.date)].mean().`

Currently I am just naively looping through each column of A and calculating B[(B.elementID==row.elementID) & (row.startDate <= B.date) & (row.endDate >= B.date)].mean(). However, both A and B have on the order of 10 million rows, and the start/end dates can be up to 2 years apart, so this approach takes way too long.

To be concrete, A looks something like

```
ID    startDate   endDate
3093  2015-01-09  2015-01-23
3093  2015-01-13  2015-03-20
3093  2015-01-20  2015-02-27
3093  2015-01-26  2015-03-06
3093  2015-01-27  2015-04-17
3093  2015-02-01  2015-07-17
3093  2015-02-03  2015-02-27
3093  2015-02-04  2016-01-15
...
```

B looks something like

```
ID   date             dataValue
512  2014-12-31       0.1285
3093 2014-12-31       0.1176
3101 2014-12-31       0.1591
3103 2015-01-12       0.3001
3105 2015-01-12       0.2306
3107 2015-01-12       0.1524
3107 2015-01-13       0.0000
3107 2015-01-14       0.1739
3112 2015-01-15       0.0370
...
```

Comment: Is the ID in `B` unique?

Comment: No, but (ID, date) combos are unique. I've edited it to be more clear.